# How to remove the foggy discoloration in polycarbonate tubes caused by acetone?

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, polymers

Unknowing that the tubes used in the centrifuge are made of polycarbonate, I cleaned them with acetone. Following, a white smoky discolouration appeared and the tubes turned opaque. Is there any way to remove this?

Comment: I think it's hopeless.

Comment: About the only way I can think of is throw out the old ones and use new ones.

Comment: I agree with the comments, but maybe it does not matter much? If the tubes are completely opaque, then you need new tubes.